# How do I resolve inconsistencies between the rules committee Commander rules and the comprehensive rules?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've heard mention that the MTGCommander rules committee maintain the rules for Commander, not Wizards. The comprehensive rules simply mentions that they maintain "additional resources", not that they maintain the rules.

There is an inconsistency between the two's rules defining color identity. [MTGCommander](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php) states:

> **3.** A card's colour identity is its colour plus the colour of any mana symbols in the card's rules text. A card's colour identity is established before the game begins, and cannot be changed by game effects.

The comprehensive rules say:

> **903.4.** The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

According to the former, [Blisterpod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlisterpod%5d) has a colorless color identity, because it has no colored symbols in its rules text to add to its color (which is none, due to devoid). According to the latter, the color identity is green, because you check each section for color, not the card as a whole.

The fact that there's a difference means we need to decide which one takes precedence. The comprehensive rules refer to the "independent rules committee" of MTGCommander, giving them *some* rules credibility. MTGCommander says "These are the official rules for Commander."

How should such inconsistencies be resolved/who actually controls the Commander rules?

Comment: Isn't the mana cost part of the rules text?

Comment: @xornob The rules text is the text frame beneath the image. The mana cost of the card itself is not part of that area.

Comment: @doppelgreener Ok, I didn't know and it seemed possible

Comment: Tabak, the MtG rules manager said devoid doesn't change color identity for Commander, siding with the comprehensive rules wording.

Comment: @CyberClaw Yes, but Tabak is the WotC rules manager, so he's tied to the comprehensive rules, rather than providing evidence that WotC maintains more authority over the rules than the Commander committee.

Comment: It's not a matter of whom has the authority (EDH team), but a matter of where the "final say" is written. We all agree that the EDH team creates the rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## How to Resolve Inconsistencies

First, try to determine whether there are actually any inconsitancies. For example, the mtgcommander.net forums have their [very own thread](http://www.mtgcommander.net/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18242) discussing the matter of Devoid specifically. The most concise explanation seems to be [the one from Carthain](http://www.mtgcommander.net/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18242&start=51):

> (...) Colour Identity is the culmination of colours + colours of mana symbols on the card. It's a purely additive situation, you can't "lose" or "undo" adding a colour to a card's colour identity.
>
> Devoid says that a card is colourless. It it's a characteristic defining ability that sets a colour (colourless is not a colour); it's not any of the mana symbols that define a colour; it's not a colour indicator on the card; Therefore, it doesn't have any impact on the colour identity of the card.

Sheldon Menery [writes](http://www.mtgcommander.net/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18242&start=6):

> Color and color identity are two different (but related) things. Colorless-ness is not part of either.

Therefore, [Blisterpod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlisterpod%5d) is colorless and has a green color identity, **according to both sets of rules.**

This being only a single case, it raises the question whether one set of rules does generally take precedence over the other, and which one does. So...

## Which Rules are the "Official" Rules?

In an effort to solve this question better than with a guess, I decided to take the time and write something up that explains the historical events as well as their implications as best as I'm able to. Because there's no set-in-stone answer to be found anywhere, I encourage you to read through all of it, even though I have my own conclusion all the way on the bottom.

#### The EDH Era

Without going too much into historical matters here, [this article](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/ways-play/godfathers-casual-2016-02-23) will tell you a whole lot about the history of the format. In any case, the format has existed under the name EDH long before WotC took it up as Commander, and *dragonhighlander.net* (now [mtgcommander.net](http://www.mtgcommander.net)) is the original web page where the rules were first made available online in order to reach a greater audience.

This doesn't really help answering the question directly, however it disproves the first paragraph in CyberClaw's answer, which states that mtgcommander.net is meant merely as a "short quick explanation without any kind of deep rule (or care on their wording)."

#### The Commander Era

WotC eventually incorporated the format into their franchise by announcing the first Commander set along with the name change from EDH to Commander, and the respective [WotC announcement](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/magic-gathering-commander-2010-12-02) mentions several important factors to the question at hand:

> (...) we recognize the importance of keeping the format as player-run, even after we produce products that officially endorse it. To that end, we worked closely with Sheldon Menery and the rest of the EDH Rules Committee (we're lucky to have one of them, Scott Larabee, in house) to make sure our product adhered to their rules and stayed true to their spirit.

And further down in the article (emphasis theirs):

> And finally ...
>
> **Wizards of the Coast and the DCI are not "taking over" the format!** We will not be managing the rules or the banned list of the Commander format, instead leaving it in the capable hands of Sheldon Menery and his rules team. They deserve all the credit for this format's popularity and we don't want to mess with a good thing!

---

### Conclusion & Implications

WotC still considers the Commander Rules Commitee as the maintainers of the rules, as evidenced rather clearly in the aforementioned sources directly from WotC. I haven't been able to find any evidence disputing what was said in those articles, or a change of mind at a later point in time.

The Commander Rules Commitee is in charge of maintaining the rules and the ban list and therefore the technically official source for rules, while WotC is incorporating those rules into the CR in a way suiting the style of the rest of the document, and likely being more precise as a result of that, making the CR the source probably best suited to resolve rule questions.
They aren't meant to be functionally different though, and if there were differences, they would likely be mistakes and the Commander Rules Commitee rules would have to take precedence (which has happened before, as acknowledged in an announcement about [former rule 903.4 about color identity](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/february-2011-update-bulletin-2011-01-27)).

Knowing all of the above, keep in mind that [Commander is a social format](http://mtgcommander.net/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=17096) - in the end, what your player group wants to play should decide which cards you're allowed to include in your deck, whether it's a Blisterpod in an otherwise colorless deck, or a [Spell Counter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpell%20Counter%5d) (just maybe keep some alternative cards around, should you meet a group who does not like the idea).

This means that ultimately, **your playgroup is the final authority on each and every rule**.

Comment: Another possibly relevant quote from Carthain in that forum thread: "This site is the "front lines" & main/direct source for all things Commander (other than offshoots such as 1v1) -- but that doesn't mean that the rules presented on the front page are written in rules-legalese". This implies that the site is in fact not intended to be the comprehensive reference for precise rulings.

Comment: Ah! Quite a thorough discussion of the issue, with the kind of references I was hoping to find - WotC announcing that MTGCommander is in charge of the rules. Interesting to see the relevant comments over time.

Comment: @Samthere: Yep, I knew most of the rough circumstances before, but reading about it in detail and collecting reliable sources was most interesting, even if it took a few hours getting everything together... glad you apprechiate it :)

Comment: @TheThirdMan You did not really answer the question btw. If there is a Commander tournament, the source of rules must be either one or the other, and house owner chooses doesn't fly there. EDH is a social "house rules" game mode. But when Wizards brought EDH to MTG (and the digital games) with Commander they specified the jargon and rules, as now it was an endorsed mode. If the rules predate and are maintained by that website, then, there is no reason for Wizards to include different but more specific wording with slightly different meaning in the comprehensive rules and then link the website.

Comment: @murgatroid99, that's the definite feel I got from all the years I played EDH and Commander. Heck, the source for rulings is the Gatherer, maintained by Wizards as well. This includes cards that have Commander specific abilities, like Akiri, Line-Slinger. If Wizards is not the final word for commander rules, what would that make of their gatherer rulings pertaining commander?

Comment: @CyberClaw: I can't tell from the question that it's at all related to tournament play, however the article I linked about Commander being a social format I linked goes into more detail about how Commander isn't necessarily workable if you turn it from a social into a competitive format, or at least something inbetween. WotC only allows reporting Commander matches as casual events, so it's a long shot to argue it's an endorsed tournament format. As for the rest of your question, you appear to have missed my point about both sets of rules being the same at their core, just differently phrased.

Comment: @CyberClaw: As for the Gatherer rulings - they don't propose rules of their own, just interpretations of the rules, applicable to that specific card, if WotC believes it's something that prevents confusion with difficult interactions (most of the time). I don't disagree with murgatroid99's point at all, and I've edited my answer to make that more clear - but you seem to equate "not intended to be most precise" as "definitely not the authority". Either way, do what I did and look for sources of your point, as opinions don't really help. If you want to discuss this further, I'll be in the chat.

Comment: @CyberClaw: I suspected you might have been misreading my post to say that the CR can't be used as a rules document, or that you should use mtgcommander.net over the CR. I edited the last segment of my answer to hopefully be more clear on that matter and resolve this dispute.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are set by the comprehensive rules. MTGCommander website is meant as a short quick explanation without any kind of deep rule (or care on their wording). They only maintain the ban-list.

The example you provided Blisterpod is not colorless, because devoid doesn't affect the color identity. It only affects the card color which is a separate element. Tabak, the rules manager, said so himself on 2 occasions:

> Devoid makes a card colorless, but it doesn't change its color identity for Commander. Black card with devoid = black decks only.
>
> [-Tabak](https://twitter.com/TabakRules/status/633428719613317120)

So, just to make it clear, Tabak, MtG rules manager, said devoid doesn't affect the color identity, siding with the comprehensive rules.

Comment: The "in any case" is wrong. Given the rule wording from MTGCommander, Blisterpod's color identity would be colorless.

Comment: @Gendolkari I believe "in any case" wasn't trying to say that it applied under both readings, but just to make clear to the asker that blisterpod's colour identity is not colourless. In any case, the wording there is a little confusing.

Comment: Yeah I just edited it to make it sound better. Color identity is not based on card color, the MTGCommander just uses it as a shorthand explanation I guess.

Comment: Lacking a backing quote, I'm posting this as a comment rather than as an answer, but the Commander rules were created by the team that now maintains mtgcommander.net, and Wizard merely chose to include those rules in their official Comprehensive Rules document - likely due to the fact that Wizards creates expansions tagretting that format. Commander is still a format maintained by mtgcommander.net, and therefore their rules should generally take precedence. That said, I agree that the phrasing is likely just a shorthand and both paragraphs mean to say the same thing.

Comment: @TheThirdMan This is probably the main thing I'm trying to figure out. Do Wizards recognise the Rules Committee as the rules arbiters, or only for maintaining the banlist? This part might be a shorthand, but it might also be a key difference. Especially since the Commander rules about mana production changed after BFZ, which could potentially be seen in part to allow devoid cards to work.

Comment: Wizards maintains the rules. This is obvious by the fact they have Commander specific wording in the rules, and the fact they published various Commander products. The team that created commander never had any official rulebook, or rulings. Their rules resumed to a few sentences that didn't clarify questions on more complex cards. I believe they haven't changed the rules in their website for like 6 or 7 years at least. They look very similar to how it looked like back when I played. But I'll check.

Comment: Yep, wording hasn't changed since the first recorded version of the site on the Way Back Machine. It doesn't look like an official source or wording for rules anyhow:
https://web.archive.org/web/20110129144949/http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php?PRINT=1

Comment: @CyberClaw Having commander specific wording in the comp rules does not make Wizards of the Coast the definitive source for commander rules. In fact, Wizards even admits that their rules are not comprehensive "900.1. This section contains additional optional rules that can be used for certain casual game variants. It is by no means comprehensive."

Comment: They also mention that "a rules committee maintains additional resources at MTGCommander.net" in rule 903.1. Why would they mention that if those rules were intended to be ignored?

Comment: Resources are not necessarily rules (although they do have rules). They maintain the official banlist. I'm guessing there was some contract signed between Wizards and "Team Commander" when Wizards decided to publish Commander products. They maintain the vision, that includes rules and ban-lists, and Wizards puts it in the official manual with the all inclusive and careful thought language rules would need. But this is me guessing.

Comment: Also Wizards makes it pretty clear the rules are the ones written in their comprehensive rules: as seen in 903.1: "The Commander variant was created and popularized by fans; an independent rules committee maintains additional resources at MTGCommander.net. The Commander variant uses all the normal rules for a Magic game, with the following additions" So, while they attribute the rules creation to them, the definitive source for rules are the ones in that document.

Comment: @CyberClaw: That's only an interpretation of what we're given, and by no means a reliable answer. I would like to see some citation on the matter.

Comment: @Rainbolt I'm pretty sure rule 900.1 just means that the rules in section 900 are not a "comprehensive" description of all casual game variants and that it should not be interpreted as restricting the variants players can apply in casual games.

Comment: Well I doubt judges in a commander tournament would reference the EDH site instead of the comprehensive rules. But on a social level (where Commander is meant to be played) such minute rules are meaningless, and house rules are king.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's one way to interpret 900.1. I found a post where [an L3 judge referenced 900.1](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/290014-ghostfire-in-edh?comment=7) in the midst of a very similar discussion about an older card, [Ghostfire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136044). So I think the rule is relevant here.

Comment: That is yet another interpretation of the statement: he's saying that section 903 may not be a complete description of the commander rules. But there's a large difference between saying that there may be some incompleteness in the comprehensive rulebook and saying that that section of the comprehensive rulebook is subordinate to and overridden by the rules written somewhere else.

Comment: @murgatroid99 If I said anywhere in my previous comments that the comp rules were subordinate to or overriden by the rules posted on MTGCommander, then I didn't mean to. Sorry for the poor communication. I think that the correct answer is "Neither set of rules is comprehensive, and you have to handle discrepancies on a case by case basis."

Comment: It doesn't make sense to handle discrepancies between the comp rules and MTGCommander on a "case by case basis". There's no logical reason to say "for this rule, the comp rules win, and for that rule, MTGCommander wins". For any reasonable consistency in rulings, you have to choose one that consistently overrides the other.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I guess I am not communicating my point very well. I love consistency, and I would love to see a solid explanation of why one set of rules is the "winner", but this answer and the subsequent comments simply don't do a very good job of explaining that. The MTGCommander literally says "These are the official rules for Commander." What evidence/logic is there for choosing the comp rules over the MTGCommander rules?

Comment: The comp rules are the official rules for Magic: the Gathering. A third party site unilaterally declaring itself to be an official source is not a good reason to accept it over the actual official rules. Even if you disregard that, MTGCommander rules are updated less frequently and have less detail than the comp rules, which is sufficient to consider it "less comprehensive".

Comment: Think of the EDH site like MtG regular manual. It's just a short explanation of how it works. Short hand rules. Comprehensive rules are the actual rules for all the minute details.

Comment: I think we probably have the answer; I think the comprehensive rules are core to the game, unless somewhere Wizards have recognised that the rules committee have some power over the rules. I have heard that people think this, but I haven't seen anything actually from Wizards about it. I'll leave it a bit longer for pondering and further feedback before accepting an answer, though.

Comment: Edited answer with quote from the MtG rules manager.